# Android: process has died after calling native touch handler

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, native, freepascal

Application crashes with no errors after passing few touch events to the native code (ARM). This happens ONLY if native handler writes a message to system log and ONLY if it is called from GLSurfaceView.onTouchEvent(). Crash happens not immediately, but after 2..10 calls, and seems not inside the native code. Although if I remove LogI(...) in the native code - it works. But if I call the same native function from another place (for example, from onDrawFrame()) - it works with no crashes.

This happens both in Android Emulator (ARM) and a real device.

Here is my Java code:

```
private class JNIView extends GLSurfaceView {
    @Override public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) {
         Log.i(TAG,"{");
         AppTouch(1, 2, 1); // <---- problem!
         Log.i(TAG,"}");
         return true;
    }
....

private class MyRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        AppDrawFrame();
        AppTouch(1, 2, 1); // <---- NO problem!
    }
...
public native void AppTouch(float x, float y, int action);
```

Native code (Pascal):

```
procedure AppTouch(env:PJNIEnv; this:jobject; x,y:jfloat; action:jint);
 begin
  try
   LogI('AppTouch: '); // <<<------ Crashing depends on this line!!!
  except
   on e:exception do LogI('Error in AppTouch: '+ExceptionMsg(e));
  end;
 end;
```

Logcat:

```
I/ApusLib (18690): {
I/ApusLib (18690): AppTouch:
I/ApusLib (18690): }
I/ApusLib (18690): {
I/ApusLib (18690): AppTouch:
I/ApusLib (18690): }
I/ActivityManager(  953): Process apus.engine3 (pid 18690) has died.
I/WindowState(  953): WIN DEATH: Window{ae0e2160 u0 apus.engine3/apus.engine3.JNIActivity}
W/ActivityManager(  953): Force removing ActivityRecord{ae02b330 u0 apus.engine3/.JNIActivity}: app died, no saved state
W/WindowManager(  953): Force-removing child win Window{ae0e5a70 u0 SurfaceView} from container Window{ae0e2160 u0 apus.engine3/apus.engine3.JNIActivity}
D/Zygote  (  648): Process 18690 exited cleanly (255)
W/WindowManager(  953): Failed looking up window
W/WindowManager(  953): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@ae0ea220 does not exist
```

There are no any stack traces or dumps in the log. Is there a way to find out the EXACT reason of application termination?

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's a threading issue with my native library. Touch handler was called from another thread probably while drawing code is running, and something were damaged.

Adding **cthreads** unit solved the problem! http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=17427.0